# SQL Update Column: Issue with Join Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the table structure as shown below. Which SQL script can I use to update the column `Size2` in the table, with the sum of column `Size`, when the animals and date are equal? Platform is SQL Server.

I want to have a column `Size2` that is the sum of the `Size` when animal names and date of weigh-in are equal to each other. There are other older dates for each animal but I only want weights from the latest date. Each date has part numbers that associate with it and start from 1 (Date1: part1,part2,part3... Date 2: part1,part2,part3, etc...) I'm struggling to put the script below into an update statement but please see the select statement.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 
(
    Size    nvarchar(50),
    Animals nvarchar(250),
    Date nvarchar(250)
    Part    int,
    Size2   nvarchar(250) 
);
```

| Size | Animals | Part | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | Pig | 1 | 20200508 |
| 40 | Pig | 1 | 20190621 |
| 60 | Tiger | 1 | 20200610 |
| 10 | Tiger | 2 | 20200610 |
| 30 | Pig | 2 | 20200508 |
| 90 | Lion | 1 | 20210708 |
| 20 | Lion | 2 | 20210708 |
| 10 | Lion | 3 | 20210708 |

This is the desired output

| Size | Animals | Part | Size2 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | Pig | 1 | 60 | 20200508 |
| 60 | Tiger | 1 | 70 | 20200610 |
| 10 | Tiger | 2 | 70 | 20200610 |
| 30 | Pig | 2 | 60 | 20200508 |
| 90 | Lion | 1 | 120 | 20210708 |
| 20 | Lion | 2 | 120 | 20210708 |
| 10 | Lion | 3 | 120 | 20210708 |

So far I have this. It does not properly populate size2 with the sum of the sizes:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET table1.size2 = table2.total_size
FROM
    table1
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT Size, Animals, Part,
    SUM(CAST(size as int)) OVER(PARTITION BY Animals) As total_size
    FROM table1
    WHERE part IS NOT NULL) AS table2
    ON table1.size = table2.size AND
    table1.animals = table2.animals AND
    table1.part = table2.part
    table1.Date = table2.Date;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The UPDATE FROM syntax is product specific.

Comment: _"Platform is SQL Server"_ Please make sure to add the proper tags when asking a question (I have added it for you now), not just mention it in passing in your question text.

Comment: Are you sure you want a windowed `SUM` in that subquery?

Comment: I usually use SUM queries but is there a better way to derive these values? I'm open to other solutions

Comment: My point is that I suspect you want just a "normal" `SUM` (with a `GROUP BY`) not a windowed `SUM`. Otherwise you'll have multiple rows for a single `Size`, `Animals` and `Part`.

Comment: I want to populate size2 with the same number since it is the sum of size1 for each animal that has the same name and latest date.

Comment: You cannot create a column via an update statement you need to alter table to do so then update as 2 statements..

Comment: Yeah the column is already created

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `CTE`'s and an `UPDATE` statement to achieve this:

1. The first `CTE` to get to get the `DENSE_RANK` based on `Animals`
   and `Date`.
2. The second `CTE` to `SUM` only the `Size` values returned in
   the first `CTE` using `WHERE DENSE_RANK = 1`.

```
WITH cte AS 
  (SELECT
  Size, Animals, Part, Size2, Date,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Animals ORDER BY Date DESC) AS dr
  FROM table1),
cte2 AS 
  (SELECT Size2, SUM(CAST(Size AS INT)) OVER (PARTITION BY Animals ORDER BY Date DESC) AS dr_sum
  FROM cte WHERE dr = 1)
UPDATE  cte2
SET Size2 = dr_sum
```

**Result:**

| Size | Animals | Part | Size2 | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | Pig | 1 | 60 | 20200508 |
| 60 | Tiger | 1 | 70 | 20200610 |
| 10 | Tiger | 2 | 70 | 20200610 |
| 30 | Pig | 2 | 60 | 20200508 |
| 90 | Lion | 1 | 120 | 20210708 |
| 20 | Lion | 2 | 120 | 20210708 |
| 10 | Lion | 3 | 120 | 20210708 |

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/IG0R7nJ-?hide=112).